# Create a report using multiple html files on R/Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, report, bookdown

I generated multiples html files from multiple Rmarkdown script and I want to create a main page with links to the different html files, a bit like a table of content.

I found the r package 'book down' but it doesn't seem to work with directly html files and I have difficulties when I tried with the Rmarkdown files due to the usage of template in these files.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a Notepad file with HTML code like this containing your links:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example1.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com">Link 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and then save it as example.html, then open it, it will be an HTML page with links.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed this solution seems to be the most effective